# Is there an ANTLR4 grammar for ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I know that there is an ANTLR3 grammar for ANTLR3, and it seems to me that the ANTLR4 distribution contains ANTLR4 grammar written in ANTLR3, but is there a grammar for ANTLR4 written in ANTLR4 itself?

Comment: This question is very relevant as the question in other words is "How to parse ANTLR4 using ANTLR4". The tool is already specified as ANTLR4. So this is not asking for recommendation. The question here is if this can be done or not and if yes, how?

Comment: Why is this closed? A perfectly valid question. E.g. you want to postprocess (pretty-print, lint, etc.) an ANTLR4 grammar itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official grammar currently, but one is available as part of ANTLRWorks 2. This grammar is definitely missing some of the error reporting capabilities that are in the official grammar, and may differ slightly in behavior.

- [GrammarLexer.g4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/grammar/experimental/GrammarLexer.g4): This is the lexer grammar. The grammar uses the `abstract=true` option, which was removed from the official ANTLR release so the grammar only works with the special [4.1-opt](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/releases/tag/4.1-opt) release in my fork of the project.
- [GrammarLexer.java](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/grammar/experimental/GrammarLexer.java): This extends the generated `AbstractGrammarLexer.java` and provides necessary implementations of `emit()` and `handleBeginArgAction()`.
- [GrammarParser.g4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/grammar/experimental/GrammarParser.g4): This is the parser grammar. It is also marked abstract, but currently doesn't use any functionality that *requires* this option so it could be removed. I included it for consistency with the code generated for the lexer.

Comment: Just started to play around with the grammars, and it looks like there is an extra comma (,) character after the last token in the `tokens` section both in GrammarLexer.g4 and GrammarParser.g4. After deleting these ANTLR generated the java files.

Comment: @TorokBalint The 4.1-opt release allows that comma, and I prefer to keep it when I have delimited lists organized with one item per line.

Answer (score 4):

There is also one on GitHub, authored by Terence Parr, himself.

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr/antlr4